# How to exit adb logcat

Tags: android

The following terminal command shows the logcat.

```
$> $SDK/platform-tools/adb logcat
```

But how do I get out of it to go back to the terminal prompt? I tried kill-server, exit etc.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd>

Comment: Isn't that like an abort of the current program? I was thinking there might be another way .... elegant exit if you will....

Comment: No, there is no other easy way... and I think this way is really elegant.

Comment: Here's the thing. I'm trying to read logcat through my app. I use Runtime.getRuntime().exec("logcat -v time MyTag:D *:S"). It all works fine but it just sits there waiting for more lines just like on a terminal. Ref : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7473469/read-logcat-from-app-not-working-correctly/

Comment: @OceanBlue Try to use `adb logcat -d`

Comment: @Cristian This approach knocks you out of interactive shell entirely. I don't find that elegant

Answer (score 25):

Using -d option will get you a one-time run of logcat.

```
adb logcat -d
```

Instead of looping, it will go back to command prompt after it prints out all the logs from log buffer. 
Each time you use this command, it always starts from the beginning of log buffer, unless you input the command below to clean the logs in log buffer:

```
adb logcat -c
```

The command above is to clean the logs in logcat buffer.

Answer (score 11):

My Suggestion:

```
    $> $SDK/platform-tools/adb logcat -c
    $> $SDK/platform-tools/adb logcat > log_file.txt &
    ... run your application ...
    $> $SDK/platform-tools/adb logcat -c
```

[Logcat Documentation](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/logcat.html)

```
-c  Clears (flushes) the entire log and exits.
```

Comment: Thank you, it's really helped me.

Answer (score 6):

I found an issue when trying with solution of [Meir Gerenstadt](https://stackoverflow.com/users/391668/meir-gerenstadt).

The `adb logcat -c` at the end doesn't really stop logcat from writing to the log_file.txt

My solution is:

```
# Clear logcat 
$> $SDK/platform-tools/adb logcat -c
# Redirect logcat to file, in background process.
$> $SDK/platform-tools/adb logcat > log_file.txt &
# Get process id of logcat background process above
$> logcat_pid=$!

... run your application ...

# Now kill the logcat background process
$> kill $logcat_pid
```

Comment: hi, @Tien, I know what u r going to do, yet I tried your solution turned out:


# Get process id of logcat background process above
$> logcat_pid=$!


"logcat_pid is not accessible"

Answer (score 0):

You can suspend the process by sending it a SIGSTP signal using CTRL+Z and issue any command you wish to, then to restart issue:

```
$> fg -1
```

Assuming you did not suspend or start any other background process from the terminal.